# How to generate graphs and charts from mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql, graph, charts

**How can I generate graphs and charts from a mysql database using php?**

I'm trying to use "chart director" but I can't even install it properly, because I'm using php version 5.3, and it's using a deprecated function `dl`.

Do you know of any alternatives that:

- fully support php 5.3
- are easy to use for beginners
- can access the mysql database and chart its data

Comment: You can use http://sg2.php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php instead of dl

Comment: Just with simple SQL query. Here you go: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-pie-chart

Comment: fusioncharts is good option too.

Comment: java command line tool showing how to create pie chart of mysql data http://www.sqldashboards.com/b/sql-pie-chart-mysql/. Call the command from php.

Comment: I quickly assembled a simple this tool  https://github.com/harish2704/sql-chart

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use JPGraph and Graphpite

http://jpgraph.net/

http://graphpite.sourceforge.net/

Comment: do you have a copy of the jpgraph?I cannot download it from their site, every browser that I have used is unable to download jpgraph, its unable to determine the download site

Comment: A very good example with php code using mysql database can be found here: http://www.css-resources.com/Make-Line-Chart-from-MySQL-Table-Data.html

Comment: Try [www.chartphp.com](http://chartphp.com)

Answer (score 14):

I use [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). They are very interactive (and very fancy I might add). You do have to get a little creative to access data from MySQL database, but if you have a general understanding of JavaScript and PHP, you should have no problems.

Comment: Hi @Brett, could you explain a little about what you mean by having to get creative to get the Data from the MySQL database? I'm in the situation where I need to draw graphs to a website from a database and highcharts looks great, I'm not very proficient at JS however.

Answer (score 10):

I use Google Chart Tools https://developers.google.com/chart/ It's well documented and the charts look great. Being javascript, you can feed it json data via ajax.

Comment: This google chart is very good, and very easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

http://pchart.sourceforge.net/ looks very good and it's free.

Comment: Version 2 is located at http://www.pchart.net/